# Changing attributes in Django Objects outside of iteration

Tags: python, django

I'm adding three attributes to a Django QuerySet that represents a hierarchical tree structure:

- a `display_name` which is added to all objects
- the id of the object's parent (or `immediate_parent`) which is added to all objects based on a condition
- a boolean `is_parent` field that should be added if and only if the object has children in the hierarchy.

The first two proved to be pretty simple to add while iterating over the QuerySet. The third proved more difficult because I was trying to modify an element outside of the one in the iteration. I tried to modify using both the `.get()` and the `.filter()` methods from the QuerySet API, but it didn't work to modify the original object. You can read more about that in the [original stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106011/on-the-fly-modification-of-django-queryset-objects).

Eventually I came up with this solution that involves iterating over the QuerySet 3 times:

```
causelist_data = CauseHierarchy.objects.filter(cause_set_version_id=cause_set_version_id).extra(order_by=['sort_order']).prefetch_related('cause_id','parent_id')
for c in causelist_data:
    c.display_name = c.cause_id.cause_name + " (" + c.cause_id.acause + ")"
    if len(c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')) == 1:
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-1]
    else:
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-2]
parents = []
for c in causelist_data:
    parents.append(int(c.immediate_parent))
for c in causelist_data:
    if int(c.cause_id_id) in parents:
        c.is_parent = True
```

This is pretty slow. Is there any way I can modify the `parent` object in the original iteration? (Any other suggestions welcome as well)

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are iterating over the queryset three times in order to get set the `immediate_parent` and later set `is_parent`. While it doesn't look like you can cut this down to a single iteration, you can definitely cut it down to two.

## Removing the extra iteration

Right now you are iterating over your queryset three times

1. Set the `immediate_parent` on the object
2. Get a list of all of the parents
3. Set `is_parent` on the object

Which works, but you can actually combine the first two iterations into a single one. This is because getting the list of the parents does not require any extra knowledge that comes after the first iteration. So you end up with

1. Set `immediate_parent` and build a list of parent ids
2. Set `is_parent` on the object if it's a parent

Or in code form

```
causelist_data = CauseHierarchy.objects.filter(cause_set_version_id=cause_set_version_id).extra(order_by=['sort_order']).prefetch_related('cause_id','parent_id')
parents = []

for c in causelist_data:
    c.display_name = c.cause_id.cause_name + " (" + c.cause_id.acause + ")"
    if len(c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')) == 1:
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-1]
    else:
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-2]
    parents.append(int(c.immediate_parent))

for c in causelist_data:
    if int(c.cause_id_id) in parents:
        c.is_parent = True
```

## Use sets where the list can only have unique values

Right now you are using a list for `parents`, so each time you `append` the parent, it gets added to the list. This means that there can be multiple ids in the list for a single parent, which doesn't make sense when we are just using it to check for the existence of the id.

You can use a `set` instead. This has the benefit of having a faster lookup time, so the second iteration won't take as long.

```
parents = set()

for c in causelist_data:
    parents.add(int(c.immediate_parent))
```

## Use `in` to check if a character is in a string

Right now in your first iteration you are looking for a `,` in the `path_to_top_parent` in order to determine if there is only a single parent in the path of now. But you're doing this by splitting the string on `,` and checking that there is only one part (so there wasn't a `,`).

```
if ',' in c.path_to_top_parent:
```

Is the same as

```
if len(c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')) > 1:
```

But it has the added benefit of making it clear why you are branching there.

## Putting it all together

```
causelist_data = CauseHierarchy.objects.filter(cause_set_version_id=cause_set_version_id).extra(order_by=['sort_order']).prefetch_related('cause_id','parent_id')
parents = set()

for cause in causelist_data:
    cause.display_name = cause.cause_id.cause_name + " (" + cause.cause_id.acause + ")"

    if ',' in cause.path_to_top_parent:
        cause.immediate_parent = cause.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-2]
    else:
        cause.immediate_parent = cause.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-1]

    parents.add(int(cause.immediate_parent))

for cause in causelist_data:
    if int(cause.cause_id_id) in parents:
        cause.is_parent = True
```